# Cannot install Composer with Xampp on Windows

Tags: php, xampp, composer-php, windows-10

I've been trying to install composer with XAMPP on Windows 10 and the installer gave the following error:

```
The PHP exe file you specified did not run correctly:
C:\xampp\php\php.exe

The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\xampp\php\php.ini

A setting in your php.ini could be causing the problem: Either the 'extension_dir' value is incorrect or the dll does not exist.

Program Output:
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_oci8_12c.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_oci.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
```

The path to php.exe is already correct and I've uncommented the extensions on php.ini.

[image: Files in /php/ext]

[image: Files in /php/ext (2)]

Thank you, and I wish you guys a good day!

Comment: After uncommenting the extensions did you restart the server?

Comment: @ParamaKar no need for that when running `php.exe` on the command line

Comment: So do the two OCI `.dll` files exist in `C:\xampp\php\ext` or not?

Comment: @Phil, the files exist on the specified path

Comment: Can you please show the results of `dir c:\xampp\php\ext\*oci*.dll`?

Comment: @Phil, the file contains thousands of lines and in hexadecimal. It won't fit here.

Comment: @Logos perhaps I got the syntax wrong (I'm not a Windows user) but I just meant for you to list all the files in `c:\xampp\php\ext` that contain "oci" in the filename

Comment: @Phil, I've edited the question. You can see that the required files do exist in the destined path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution myself. It appears that the Composer is incompatible with php 7.0.0. I downloaded and installed Xampp with PHP 5.6.0 in it and now the installation is successful.

Answer (score 5):

I know, I am too late hare but if anybody still looking for the answer here it is...

- Go to your xampp\php\php.ini
- Press ctrl+f to find extension_dir and change its relative path to
  absolute path e.g from extension_dir="\ext" to extension_dir="E:\xampp\php\ext"
- Press ctrl+f to find browscap and change its path e.g from
  browscap="\xampp\php\extras\browscap.ini" to
  browscap="E:\xampp\php\extras\browscap.ini"
- Save the file and restart the xampp

try again with the composer installer good luck with it...

---

Comment: Dude you saved my life 4 years after your reply! Still a valid fix :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using portable XAMPP then you will get similar PHP warning. follow the instruction below to solve the warnings:

Open php.ini

1. to solve extension dir and extension related warning simply change the 
   extension_dir = "\xampp\php\ext"
   to
   extension_dir = "./ext"
2. to solve
   PHP Warning:  Cannot open '\xampp\php\extras\browscap.ini' for reading in Unknown on line 0 zend_mm_heap corrupted

Change:
browscap = "\xampp\php\extras\browscap.ini"
to
browscap = "[directory]:\xampp\php\extras\browscap.ini"

Comment: Best Answer  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. When I wanted to install composer with XAMPP give me an error with a variable PHPRC was not correct and also I had a problem with the variable "extension_dir =". I solved like this:

1. Change the variable PHPRC which is in "Environments Variables" of windows. I had C:\Program Files\PHP, I change by C:\Program Files\XAMPP\php. (Probably because I had installed before other versions of PHP as Bitnami).
2. In the file php.ini which is in C:\Program Files\XAMPP\php folder, I open the file I had "extension_dir = ".ext/" and I changed by ' extension_dir = "C:\Program Files\XAMPP\php\ext" ' aim to the folder "EXT" which contains all DLL of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

1.Open php.ini located in your "php" folder for example in xampp the file is in XYZ:\xampp\php\

2.Find "extension=php_openssl.dll"

3.";extension=php_openssl.dll" - remove ";"

4.Restart your xampp (or whatever u use), extension should be loaded after that.

5.Try again to install composer.

Comment: The error got worse, now there is another line that says : "PHP Warning:  Module 'openssl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0"

Comment: did you restart your xamppp??

Comment: How? I restarted the apache though

Comment: As u do always. But i would prefer to right click the xampp control panel and choose run as Administrator.

Comment: Sorry but, your solution doesn't work for me. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Composer]

In the next step, you would need php.exe path to proceed with the composer setup and provide the path of php.exe

[image: PHP in Xampp]

After installing the composer, you must enable the extension (php_intl.dll) in your php.ini file. To enable the extension, go to your php.ini and uncommenting the line “extension=php_intl.dll” or without dll and just remove semicolon “;” from the starting of the line and restart your XAMPP control panel.

That's how you do it.

Reference: https://www.cloudways.com/blog/how-to-install-magento-2-on-localhost/

Comment: "The path to php.exe is already correct" it says in the question. Not an helpful answer, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

I got here for a almost similar issue.

The problem was I installed XAMPP in Program Files, and it sounds like it's not  properly handled.

I reinstalled XAMPP at the root of `C:` (default installer configuration) and composer now works like a charm with PHP7

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get results after typing php in the console, your problem may be caused by this.

I solved my problem by adding PHP to the environment variables.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31413050)